# How to get only time from time picker in android?

Tags: android

I am creating a scheduler for my app in which i want to set time from time picker.Problem i am facing is that i am getting time with date.Here is the code please suggest how to do this .

```
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener t = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    //etTime.setText(fmtTime.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
    Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

    /*calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);*/

    if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
        //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
        calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    setAlarm(calSet);

 }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set time like this..

```
 TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener t = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    textview.settext("Time:"+hourOfDay+":"+minute);


 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

//int hourOfDay conatins hours of day and int minute will contains minutes.use this variables to set time.

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
String s;
Format formatter;
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, tp.getCurrentHour());
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, tp.setCurrentMinutes());
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
s = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
```